# Make multiple request in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ember.js, mongoose

I'm trying to reach different select's from another select with MongoDB database with mongoose to redirect to Emberjs front-end.

If the text above it's not clear, look at the schema of the database:

```
// I already get the exam content given an id
Exam:{ 
    ...
    collections:[{
         question: Object(Id)
    }]
    ...
}
```

and in the question schema it's:

```
// I want to get content of this giving an id 
question:{
     ...
     questions: String, // I want to get this given an Id exam
     value: Number      // and this
     ...
 }
```

I tried to get it getting the objects id of the collections and then make a for to extract each question, and save the returned values into a json variable like this:

```
Test.findById(id, 'collections', function(err, collections){
   if(err)
   {
      res.send(err);
   }
   var result ={}; //json variable for the response
   // the for it's with the number of objectId's that had been found
   for(var i = 0; i < collections.collections.length; i++) 
   {
   // Send the request's to the database
      QuestionGroup.findById(collections.collections[i].id, 'questions').exec(function(err, questiongroup)
      {
          if(err)
          {
             res.send(err);
          }
          // save the results in the json
          result.questiongroup = questiongroup;
          // prints questions
          console.log(result);
      });
      // it return's {}
      console.log(result);
   }
   // also return {}
   console.log(result);
   res.json({result: result});
});
```

It's there a way to save the requests into a variable and return it like a json to the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the query within the loop executes in async manner you'll have send response once everything finished execution.

For eg.

```
Test.findById(id, 'collections', function(err, collections) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  }
  var result = []; //json variable for the response

  function done(result) {
    res.json({
      result
    });
  }

  for (var i = 0, l = collections.collections.length; i < l; i++) {
    // i need needs to be in private scope
    (function(i) {
      QuestionGroup.findById(collections.collections[i].id, 'questions').exec(function(err, questiongroup) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        // save the results in the json
        result.push(questiongroup);
        if (l === i + 1) {
          done(result);
        }
      });
    })(i);
  }
});
```

NOTE: untested, and you might have to handle errors appropriately

Comment: Thank you very much, I dind't see that you can populate an array first and then send as a response, the codes it's working, and know I can go deeper in my solution, thanks.